# Running LND on testnet and mainnet at the same time on the same pc

Tags: lightning-network-daemon

I have two instances of bitcoind running, one on mainnet, one on testnet, without any problems.

I can't seem to find any decent documentation on running two instances of LND at the same time on the same computer. Currently I switch between the two.

Is it possible? Are there caveats? Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried creating two different lnd.conf files, having different ports specification and matching the bitcoin.conf spec, and running two instances of lnd specifing the parameter --configfile?

Comment: @StefanoAngieri Yup, you were right. I've answered my own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly possible to run several LND nodes on the same computer.

This is how I did it:

- create separate folders for each LND node
- In each folder create a lnd.conf file
- make sure you set the datadir and the logdir to point to the folders you just created
- make sure that each configuration uses **different ports for rpclisten, listen and restlisten**
- adjust all other configuration to your liking. You can have multiple clients point to the the same btcd client (that's the one I used, but I'm sure it also would work with bitcoind) and the same chain or different chains
- run `lnd --configfile=path/to/your/lnd.conf` for each lnd client you want to run

#### "pro"-tip

I've made aliases in `.bashrc` for the lnd and lncli commands for each different node.
So:

```
alias lnd-alice="lnd --configfile=path/to/alice/lnd.conf"
alias lnd-bob="lnd --configfile=path/to/bob/lnd.conf"
alias lncli-alice="lncli --rpcserver=localhost:10001 --macaroonpath=path/to/alice/data/chain/bitcoin/mainnet/admin.macaroon"
alias lncli-bob="lncli --rpcserver=localhost:10002 --macaroonpath=path/to/bob/data/chain/bitcoin/testnet/admin.macaroon"
```

To run the lnd node for alice I just type `lnd-alice` and then `lncli-alice create` if it's the first time or `lncli-alice unlock` if the wallet is already initialized. (The macaroon path isn't needed for `create` and `unlock` but it doesn't hurt either.)
Same thing for Bob.

This guide was very helpful in finding the right info: https://dev.lightning.community/tutorial/01-lncli/index.html